# Countdown timer to a specific hour everyday

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to countdown to a specific time of the day everyday in a specific timezone(GMT +2), but once I change my timezone locally, the countdown timer changes according to that timezone.

I have tried to use a UNIX timestamp(just like in PHP) but that didn't work as well - the time still changes upon changing the timezone.

```
var realD = new Date();
var realHours = realD.getHours();
var realMinutes = realD.getMinutes();
var realSeconds = realD.getSeconds();
var d = new Date(Date.UTC(2017, 8, 28, 18, realMinutes, realSeconds));

d.setUTCHours(d.getUTCHours() - 4);

document.getElementById("date").textContent = (d.getUTCFullYear() + '-' + (d.getUTCMonth()) + '-' + 
      (d.getUTCDate()) + ' - Time: - ' + (d.getUTCHours()) + ':' +
      (d.getUTCMinutes()) + ':' + (d.getUTCSeconds())
);
```

This is what I have so far.

Comment: `new Date()` will always give you system time and this is dependent on local timezone. Instead, send timestamp form server and process

Comment: @Rajesh unfortunately, using PHP on this one is not possible.

Comment: Save timestamp in html page as global variable and the use it. Send timestamp as a cookie || queryParam or any other way. Point is, if you are using `new Date()`, you will always rely on the system date/time.